# Fatal error: Cannot access empty property

Tags: php, pdo

i have got that error and the line was this :

```
   $stations=$this->$db->query('SELECT * from service_stations');
```

the $db variable is declared private and i use it in the __construct function like this:

```
public function __construct() {
                    //after including the config file
                $host=DB_HOST;
            $dbname=DB_NAME;
            $dbuser=DB_USER;
            $dbpsw=DB_PASSWORD;
         try{
            $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE]=PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
            $this->db=new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpsw, $pdo_options);
            }
         catch(Exception $e)
            {
            die('Erreur: '.$e->getMessage());
            }
    }
```

thx in advance :)

Comment: Please stop writing tags in your question titles. You've done it almost all of them.

Comment: I'd made pretty much the same mistake, the answer to this question is very helpful

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have probably made a typo:

```
$stations=$this->db->query('SELECT * from service_stations');
//               ^
// No $ here ----/
```

Answer (score 9):

You probably meant to write `$this->db` instead of `$this->$db`. The former accesses the property `db`, the latter access the property, those name is stored in the `$db` variable. And as this variable is not defined, you end up accessing an empty property, as the error message indicates.

Comment: Seriously I make mistakes with $ and variable placement all the time, whether it's leaving it out or object property access. PHP has some usability issues with its language design.