# Keep getting "undefined variable" error when I try to excute my code

Tags: php, forms, laravel, eloquent, models

I keep getting this error:

> Undefined variable: sampleRecord

while working on this chunk of code at work and no one in my cube cluster can see the problem.

Here is the constructor:

```
  public function __construct(SamplesForm $samplesForm, SamplePartNumberForm       

  $samplePartNumberForm,sampleRepository $sampleRepository, 
  SamplePartNumberRepository   
  $samplePartNumberRepository, SamplePartNumberRecord
  $samplePartNumberRecord, SampleRecord $sampleRecord)
  {
    $this->samplesForm = $samplesForm;
    $this->samplePartNumberForm = $samplePartNumberForm;
    $this->sampleRepository = $sampleRepository;
    $this->samplePartNumberRepository = $samplePartNumberRepository;
    $this->samplePartNumberRecord = $samplePartNumberRecord;
    $this->sampleRecord = $sampleRecord;
  }
```

Here is the chunk causing the error:

```
public function show($sample_id)
{
    return View::make('samples.show')->with([
        $sampleRecord->sampleRepository->find($sample_id),
        $sampleRecord->getSamplePartNumberRecord,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Replace `$sampleRecord` with `$this->sampleRecord` in the second method (twice).

Comment: now I am getting the following error: Cannot access empty property

Comment: You've probably made [this new error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772807/fatal-error-cannot-access-empty-property). I found that link, incidentally, by searching for your new error message - a good habit to get into when debugging.

Comment: No this is the code $sample = $this->sample->sampleRepository->find($sample_id),
            $sample = $this->sample->getSamplePartNumberRecord,

Comment: As far as I can see, `$this->sample` does not exist at all. See my answer for a guesstimate as to the possible cause. If that doesn't fix it, please add in your property declarations into your question (these will be `protected` or `private` variables at the start of the class).

Answer (score 2):

Instance variables in PHP classes must always be qualified:

```
class Foo {
    private $bar;

    function baz () {
        return $bar;       // bad - undefined lexical variable
        return $this->bar; // correct
    }
}
```

Thus, when you refer to `$sampleRecord` it's trying to use an undefined lexical variable instead of what you mean which is `$this->sampleRecord`, the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I see the pickle you are in - two in fact:

The first problem is that `$sampleRecord` is not local, and so should refer to the instance property, which is `$this->sampleRecord`.

The second issue is that, at a guess, `$sampleRepository` is not a property on `$sampleRecord`, since it is a property on the current class. Try the following instead:

```
public function show($sample_id)
{
    return View::make('samples.show')->with([
        $this->sampleRepository->find($sample_id),
        $this->sampleRecord->getSamplePartNumberRecord,
    ]);
}
```

As an aside, your constructor has six arguments, which is generally thought to be too many. It may be worth refactoring this, as a separate task.